# How to use correctly InputStream.read(buffer) method and process my Data?

Tags: java, android, sockets, buffer, inputstream

I have to create an application in Android for connect my Galaxy S3 with another device, in this answer I call it device1. I use socket and InputStream.
- first: I connect my phone using socket, when connection is established, device1 send me some string that I store in one buffer.

- second: I send to device1 an "s" string, when device1 receive this string, it send me continuos data without interruption.

-tree: I want read this data and do some elaboration

The problem is that InputStream.read(buffer) is blocking, so I receive data but I'm not able to processing it.

Here my code:

```
public void run() {             

                try {
                    socket=new Socket();  
                    socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ipDevice,portDevice),20); //settare il timeout per evitare che tutto si blocchi su receive
                    String controllo="connesso";





                    showToast(controllo);
                    InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                    byte[] buffer_controllo = new byte[1024];
                                            int count_bytes_read;
                    char[] chars ;
                    String str;

                    count_bytes_read = is.read(buffer_controllo); //lettura del buffer

                    str=new String(buffer_controllo);
                    chars=new char[count_bytes_read];



                    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw, true);
                    out.write("s");
                    byte[] buffer_dati = new byte[1024];
                    int count_bytes_read2=0;
                    while(count_bytes_read2!=-1){
                    count_bytes_read2 = is.read(buffer_dati); //PROBLEM HERE
                    }
                    str=new String(buffer_dati);
                    chars=new char[count_bytes_read];

                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    String controllo="non connesso";
                    showToast(controllo);
                    try {
                        socket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    String controllo="non connesso";
                    showToast(controllo);
                    try {
                        socket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    e.printStackTrace();                    
                }  
                finally{
                    if(socket!=null){
                        try {
                            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
                            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw, true);
                            out.write("z");                 
                            out.flush();
                            socket.close();                         
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        });
        //Avvio del Thread
        cThread.start();
```

As you can see the problem is here:

```
count_bytes_read2 = is.read(buffer_dati);
```

this read method is blocking, I receive infinite number of data from device1, so I can't take my buffer dati and doing some elaboration on it.
How can I take this data during the execution of the read method? I have to block read for some time or there are other solution?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[DataFetcher](http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/io/DataFetcher.java) is a class I wrote to handle these sorts of issues. It's a threaded reader that operates through the listener/callback pattern... though it can also be used to read a stream fully. I think this could be useful in solving your problem

Comment: Thank you, I have to study your class and understund how to use it.

Comment: YOu might want to look through http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/io/IOUtils.java to get a sense of how to use this... Or just to use IOUtils directly

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make sense. You're reading from the stream until end of stream and only then are you doing anything with the data.

The data processing should happen inside the read loop.

And of course if the device sends infinitely it will never disconnect at all, so end of stream will never arrive.

Comment: infact the problem is the end of stream will never arrive and I can't do data processing. Can I create another Thread where I don't read data but just process?